Implementing Data Observability and Tracing on API Endpoints
I'm looking to set up a system on my API endpoints (Node.js and Fastify) that can trace and log the state of the data at key points in the code, especially for endpoints making SOAP calls to third-party services.
The main goal is to have better visibility and control over what is being sent and received during these SOAP interactions.
Additionally, in case a SOAP call fails or encounters an issue, I want to be able to analyze what was transmitted and track the data's evolution throughout the API process.
Could Prometheus and Grafana be a solutión to this?
What would be an optimal solution to apply on a large codebase? Is this approach suboptimal?
An example of what I'm trying to achieve could look like this:
myEndpoint(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) 
{ 
// ...some logic 
emit signal with specific data 

// ...some logic 
emit signal with specific data 

makingSoapCall() 
emit signal with specific data 

// ...some logic
}

